# Sync extensions and settings across profiles in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

I have several (3) Firefox profiles. One is for day-to-day usage, the "master" profile, one is for sites I'd rather keep out of my day-to-day history, but still want to keep in history and one where I prefer to keep history blank. Basically, I would like to synchronise extensions and settings across them but keep all personal details separate.

One option I have found is [Siphon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/siphon-add-on-synchronizer/). Unfortunately, it does not appear to synchronise browser or extension settings, only the extensions themselves (i.e. which ones are installed).

I'm happy with periodically running a script (e.g. batch file) or program that will copy relevant files across.

I've noticed some extensions (e.g. Adblock Plus) will create their own folders or files in the profile folder, so there isn't really a constant list of files and folders that I need to copy.

I guess my question kind of becomes: **which files or folders are not related to extensions in a Firefox profile**, so I can assume all others *are* related and then copy and overwrite those other files while keeping/ignoring existing personal data, such as history, bookmarks, passwords, etc. A list would be nice, I am perfectly capable of writing such a script or program myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile files and folders are detailed at http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox (also info at http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Profiles )